Syncing Document Library Files With On-Prem Network Drive
I'm quite new to SharePoint so I apologize if this has an obvious answer but information online seems to be relatively mixed or unclear in terms of my particular situation.
I'm looking to have a SharePoint site for my department with a document library for all of our regularly used files. However, many people here are very change adverse and are very much against the idea of going to a different location to access the files instead of their current location on the network drive.
My question is whether there is a way to have the files sync between the document library and their current location on the network drive. I want to have all the obvious benefits of SharePoint but also try to maintain the familiar access location for those who may not be ready to jump on board right away and reach everything from SharePoint. The version in the network drive doesn't have to be a live syncing copy of the file, even a link to the file's actual document library location would work.
Based on what I've read, it seems like its possible using OneDrive, but despite everyone here having their own personal OneDrive, my company is very slow on embracing new technology so there likely won't be a move away from the current on-prem network shares for quite a while.
